# How to get from discrete Fourier transform formulas to the continuous ones?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I read on the internet about how discrete Fourier transform works. Based on that, I made up these formulas. A discrete function $g(t)$ takes $N$ values at equally spaced intervals between $t=a$ and $t=b$. $g(a)=g(b)$. Now, the values of the function at $a, a+\frac{b-a}{N}, a+\frac{2(b-a)}{N},......a+\frac{(N-1)(b-a)}{N}$ can be described by the sum of cosine functions of frequencies $k=0,1,2,...,N-1$. The "component function" of frequency $k$ is given by:

$$f_{k}(z)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}g\left( a+\frac{n(b-a)}{N}\right) \cos{\left( \frac{2k\pi}{N}(z-n)\right)}\; \; \; \; ....(1)$$

I prefer it in this form because I can't get my head around Euler's formula.

so, $$f\left(a+\frac{z(b-a)}{N}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}f_{k}(z)\; \; \; \; ....(2)$$

This $f\left(a+\frac{z(b-a)}{N}\right)$ function matches the values of the $g(t)$ function at $z=0, 1, 2....N-1$

What if $g(t)$ was a continuous function? Should I just let $N\rightarrow \infty$?

I substituted $\frac{z}{N}=x$, $\frac{n}{N}=l$ and $\frac{1}{N}=dl$ to get these equations:

$$f_{k}(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}g\left(a+l(b-a)\right)\cos\left(2k\pi(x-l)\right)dl\; \; \; \; ....(3)$$

$$f(a+x(b-a))=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_{k}(x)\; \; \; \; ....(4)$$

By varying $x$ from $0$ to $1$, we get values of the function $f$ from $a$ to $b$. Have I done it right? Do these values match the values of the continuous function $g(t)$ in the interval $(a,b)$. Also, how do i get from here to representing a continuous function $g(t)$ on the entire real line, i.e. from $a=-\infty$ to $b=\infty$? In my equation $(4)$, the frequency varies form $0$ to $\infty$ in jumps of $1$ while in the Wikipedia article on Fourier transform, frequency varies continuously from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ in the formula.

Comment: Letting $N \to \infty$ in the discrete Fourier transform you'll get the Fourier series. The Fourier transform can be then obtained letting $T \to \infty$, at least when $f,\hat{f}$ are Schwartz. But proving the Fourier inversion theorem directly is much easier. You'll need the Fourier transform of distributions to unify all this.

Comment: @reuns What is $T$? And what does Schwartz mean? I let $N\rightarrow \infty$ in my post. Have I done it right?

Comment: Not quite, the target is to obtain the Fourier series theorem : $f(x) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty c_m e^{2i \pi m x} $ where $c_m = \int_0^1 f(x) e^{-2i \pi m x}dx$ for $f \in C^1$ and $1$-periodic.

Comment: For this look at $F_{N}(k) =\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f(\frac{n}{N}) e^{-2i \pi n k /N}$ so that $\lim_{N \to \infty} F_{N}(k) =\int_0^1 f(x) e^{-2i \pi kx}dx$. What do you get when applying the inverse DFT to $F_{N}$ ?

Comment: @reuns I don't understand it in terms of Euler's formula. Can you tell me, in terms of sinusoids, what would be the "component function" of frequency $k$ for a continuous function $g(t)$ in the interval $(a,b)$? I found it to be

$$f_{k}(x)=∫_{0}^{\infty}g(a+l(b−a))cos(2kπ(x−l))dl$$

Comment: Told you, if $g$ is a function $(a,b) \to \mathbb{C}$, without loss of generality assume $a=0,b=1$, then $f(x) = g(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)$ is $1$-periodic and you can look at its Fourier series $\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty c_m e^{2i \pi m x}$. If $f$ is $C^1$ then the series converges to $f$.

Comment: So forget about the Fourier transform and $\int_0^\infty$..

Comment: @reuns For $a=0$ and $b=1$, I find the component function of frequency $k$ to be $f_{k}(x)=\int_0^{\infty}g(l)\cos({2k\pi (x-l)})dl$ and these component function should be added from $k=0$ to $\infty$ to get the original function. I guess you're saying the component function of frequency $k$ should be $c_ke^{2i\pi kx}$ and these components functions should be added from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. How do we calculate these $c_k$ coefficients?

Comment: @reuns I'm sorry. You already wrote told me the formula for $c_k$ coefficients.

Comment: @reuns Can you tell me the formulas of the component functions and their coefficients without using Euler's formula (i.e. by using sinusoids)?

Comment: $e^{2i \pi m x} = \cos(2\pi m x)+i \sin(2\pi m x)$ **is a (complex) sinusoid**

Comment: If we use complex numbers it is not for nothing, and it is a prerequisite for Fourier analysis.

Comment: @reuns I don't think complex numbers are a necessary if $g(t)$ is a real function. The equation (1) in my post gives the component function of frequency $k$ of a discrete real function $g(t)$ without using complex numbers. It is just a sum of sinusoids which gives another sinusoid function $f_k(z)$

Comment: For complex sinusoids, the phase (= shift) is just a multiplication by a complex number. That's the core idea of the Fourier transform, so don't try avoiding it.